# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: tensorflow

I just installed tensorflow gpu v1.7 through pip. I also installed CUDA v9.0 and CUDNN v7 on a Windows 10.

My graphics card is the NVidia GTX 1060 6 GB with driver version:  22.21.13.8554 
While trying to import tensorflow on Python 3.6.4, I get the following error:

```
 Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime
 ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Technotronics Ltd\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: It is fairly hard to tell anything concrete from this info. You can try filing an issue in TF github with much more info. Else you can try following some windows installation tutorials like this one: https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin

Comment: @iga find the update above with more information. It's been hours that I've been trying

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386. If it does not help, as I said before, I would suggest a either commenting on this github issue or filing a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy & low-end CPU (without AVX) support

If your CPU didn't support AVX instructions, you will get ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Win 10) or ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795 (Win 7) when using tensorflow official release 1.6.0 and up (pip install tensorflow)
You can use pip install [filename].whl which file download from sse2 folder instead of using official AVX binary.

refer:
https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

It worked for me